# About Grades in School

Tags: meaning

In what follows, I write some sentences (about my son in elementary school), which are word by word translations from Persian to English. Each sentence is self-explanatory, but native people may say something else with the same meaning. Please let me know if they are correct:

1) My son finished grade 1 (is "finished" a proper verb?)

2) My son starts grade 2 (is "starts" a proper verb?)

3) My son begins grade 2 (is "begins" a proper verb?)

4) My son is in grade 2 (is "is" a proper verb?)

5) My son goes to grade 2 (is "goes" a proper verb?)

Comment: Idiomatically speaking, your examples 2 + 3 are *extremely* unlikely "sentences / standalone utterances" in the exact form as given. We might use the "Present as Future" verb form ***if there's an associated time-based adverbial element*** - for example, *My son starts Grade 2 **next week*** - but in casual conversational contexts we'd usually use a "continuous" form there anyway: *My son **is starting** Grade 2 **next week***.

Comment: It's not clear what your question are. Some of them may be ok grammar, but I don't know what you intend to say. For example, *My son starts grade 2* is correct, but it would be unlikely except in particular contexts. I suggest that you try to explain more precisely what you think the sentences mean.This can be quite difficult when describing time relationships.

Comment: @Lambie - Apparently, you've never read [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=GTO4ngEACAAJ).

Comment: "Go to [number] grade" is not common. "Go to first grade" is like "go to high school". But the expression is not a substitute for "be in x grade", as relevant here to the OP.